# How do I maximize windows in games?

Tags: raspbian

I have been installing some of the games on this list.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51794

But so far only one could be maximized so that the game occupies the whole screen. Most games only allow the original window size and when I click maximize nothing happens. Other games do maximize the window but the actual game rendering is still the same size and does not occupy the entire window.

Is this typical? Is it possible to somehow force the window to be maximized?

Its a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian.

Comment: I'm guessing raster graphics games don't scale their size. They count pixels not distance.